C++ 11 std::is_integral
Изучаю С++ 11 Поддержка компилятором свойств типа в частности std::is_integral.
Объясните пожалуйста в каких случаях при написании кода на С++ std::is_integral может быть полезен? Мне не совсем понятно, если int это целочисленный тип и программисту это известно - то зачем его еще раз проверять? Например зачем проверять так при помощи is_integral:
std::cout << std::is_integral<int>::value << std::endl;


Например, вы хотите проверить, что ваш шаблонный тип может служить индексом.

а можно имя переменной использовать для is_integral? например int a = 10; каким то образом при помощи is_integral проверить переменная a целая или нет, можно?

is_integral<decltype(a)>::value`
